# What is the "control mode" in tmux?

Tags: tmux

According to `man tmux` to check the launch option:

> -C:   Start in control mode (see the CONTROL MODE section). Given
>            twice (-CC) disables echo.

Then in the control mode section of the `man tmux`, there is the following description:

```
CONTROL MODE
     tmux offers a textual interface called control mode.  This allows
     applications to communicate with tmux using a simple text-only protocol.

     In control mode, a client sends tmux commands or command sequences
     terminated by newlines on standard input.  Each command will produce one
     block of output on standard output.  An output block consists of a %begin
     line followed by the output (which may be empty).  The output block ends
     with a %end or %error.  %begin and matching %end or %error have two
     arguments: an integer time (as seconds from epoch) and command number.
     For example:

           %begin 1363006971 2
           0: ksh* (1 panes) [80x24] [layout b25f,80x24,0,0,2] @2 (active)
           %end 1363006971 2

     The refresh-client -C command may be used to set the size of a client in
     control mode.

     In control mode, tmux outputs notifications.  A notification will never
     occur inside an output block.
```

I'm not sure what it means, but at least as far as I try a few commands and try to see the looks and feels of it via (`tmux -CC`), it looks like the same as when I launch via `tmux new-session`.

So what is the "control mode" and what makes it different from the normal mode?

---

#### EDIT

I found that the session and the window that was launched via the control mode (`-CC`) does not react to the keyboard shortcut of the tmux commands, such as window split. So what is the point of using the control mode in the first place?

Comment: tmux does support copy and paste, see `capture-pane` and `save-buffer` and related commands

Comment: @thrig Sorry what I read was wrong; tmux does support it but does not the mouse-based copy & paste. It seems feasible via third-party plugins like `tmux-yank`, though I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Do you already have a `tmux` session running when you try `tmux -C` or `tmux -CC`?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I tried both situations but the result was consistent.

Comment: @Blaszard if you enable mouse support, you can enable copy by highlighting with your mouse.

Comment: In regards to control mode, it’s useful for applications interacting with it. I use iterm and it supports tmux integration via control mode.

Comment: @rovr138 I'm not sure what it means. If it is control mode, what makes it differet from without it? I use iTerm2 but don't understand when to use it and when not.

Comment: So tmux control mode allows parsing and interactions with other applications. Those are the control codes that @meuh mentioned. You can check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24419304 to see how to configure it. Basically it becomes ‘native’ instead of on the CLI.

Comment: Have you tried using control mode to connect (`attach`) to an existing session?

Answer (score 25):

I'm on a Mac and I use iTerm2.  As far as I know it's the only terminal emulator that has tmux integration.  You start by doing `tmux -CC` and iTerm will control your tmux session.  This means you can use iTerm2 normally as you usually do (CMD-D to split a window vertically, CMD-SHIFT-D split it horizontally).  You can use your mouse to reposition the panes instead of using `C-b {`.  You don't need to use the prefix at all.  You don't have any problems with copy and paste either when you're dealing with panes.

tl;dr Using `tmux -CC` allows you to use tmux "natively" on terminals that support it.  So far I haven't seen any linux terminals that support it, only iTerm2 on a Mac.

Comment: [tmux - Control mode](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Control-Mode) says "_It was designed and written by George Nachman and allows his iTerm2 terminal to interface with tmux and show tmux panes using the iTerm2 UI_"

Answer (score 10):

The interesting aspect of control mode is that
you can write a background process that listens to a real tmux process. It gets notifications of
things happening in the real tmux, and it can then send
commands. If you use 2
terminals and run a normal session in one

```
tmux new -s mysession
```

and in the other

```
tmux -C attach -t mysession
```

then when you split windows, add new ones, or close them in the normal tmux
you will get lines like

```
%layout-change @2 91a8,80x23,0,0[80x11,0,0,5,80x11,0,12,7]
%window-add @3
%window-close @1
```

in the control tmux, to which you can react by writing a program. To help
there is a [python library](https://github.com/tony/libtmux) to exploit
this mechanism. See the examples there.

Comment: This is silly but I want to thank you for explaining it in a different way from everyone else. In doing so, you gave me a pretty cool idea. I sometimes tinker on little programs I make that implement terminal UIs (little reinventions of `curses` pretty much). So, what I'd been doing with this was assembling little libraries used for unit tests that basically spawn panes inside tmux, because it is a nice PTY sandbox and is capable of displaying test outputs in parallel on one screen, and nothing revs my engine like tests running in parallel. Now I know to use this mode to command the tmux!

Answer (score 7):

`tmux` control mode is not intended to be used directly.  It changes `tmux`'s behavior from being interactive to being more like a "proxy".  The way it's intended to be used is by being invoked in a terminal emulator that supports this feature, such as iTerm2.  Unfortunately, there are no Linux terminals that currently support control mode.  (Though [Terminator](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/79) seems to be making progress.)

This is a killer feature.

As an example of how it's used, consider a workflow that involves `ssh`ing to a remote server.  While you're working on that server if you want to start another session you must create a new `ssh` connection (not difficult, but a hassle, and a minor context switch).

Enter `tmux`.

`tmux` can create multiple remote sessions over your single connection (hence the "multiplexer" in the name), and display them in multiple tabs and split panes.  This certainly works, but I find the key combinations required to navigate `tmux` to be just cumbersome enough to make me wish for something better.  If only there were a way for tabs and split panes on the remote to be just as fluid and natural as in a native, local terminal emulator...

Enter `tmux -CC`.

`tmux` control mode allows a terminal emulator that supports it to control the `tmux` session by issuing commands directly to it (see meuh's answer).  For instance, you could open a new pane/tab in your remote session, but using the same key strokes/commands as you would for opening a local pane/tab, and it would **be** a local pane/tab, but connected to your remote session.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing similar results from `tmux -CC` as you would from `tmux new-session` because you didn't specify a command, so `tmux` uses the default, which *is* `new-session`:

> *command [flags]*
>
> This specifies one of a set of commands used to control **tmux**, as described in the following sections. If no commands are specified, the **new-session** command is assumed.

Adding `-CC` doesn't appear to change that.  To control the existing session, you should attach to it in control mode:

```
tmux -C attach
```

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding, control mode is like normal client. The difference is in control mode. `tmux` client read command from stdin and send to `tmux` server. In the reverse direction, client in control mode receives message from server, and print to stdout instead of draw the terminal as normal client does.